# C++ string-like class with implicit conversion

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I have a couple of string-like classes that can be implicitly converted to strings.  I have a few uses for these; one example is to hold text that needs to be translated at runtime by [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/):

```
class TranslatableString
{
public:
  explicit TranslatableString(const char *s) : native_text_(s) {}
  operator const char *() const { return gettext(native_text_); }

  // Or not - see below:
  operator const std::string() const { return gettext(native_text_); }

private:
  const char * const native_text_;
};
```

Now I'm trying to make using this class as simple as possible (i.e., using it should be as much like a string literal as possible).  In particular, I'd like for both of the following sample usages to work:

```
const TranslatableString HELLO = TranslatableString("Hello, world!");

std::string ExampleA() {
  return HELLO;
}

void ExampleB() {
  std::string s;
  s = HELLO;
}
```

Is there any way to make both examples work?

- If I include `operator std::string`, then ExampleB fails to compile, saying that there's an ambiguity between `std::string::operator=(const char *)` and `std::string operator=(const std::string&)` (which makes sense).
- If I don't include `operator std::string`, then ExampleA fails to compile; apparently implicitly converting a TranslatableString to const char * to std::string is not allowed, although I don't understand C++'s implicit conversion rules well enough to explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one user-defined conversion is allowed in each conversion sequence, that's why you can't go "through" a `const char*`. (Note that `const char*` to `std::string` is also a user-defined conversion).

Do you need the conversion to `const char*`? Without it (and with coversion to `std::string`), both examples would work.

It might also be worth considering storing the data as `std::string` internally, instead of `const char*`. You wouldn't have to worry about deallocation issues, the data "disappearing" under your hands etc.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks.  (This particular class is only designed to be used with string literals, so `const char *` is fine; elsewhere, I almost always use `std::string`.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to give up on having `operator const char *`.  Make it `explicit` (C++11) or provide it as a `c_str` method instead.

Converting `TranslatableString` to `const char *` to `std::string` is not allowed as it contains two user-defined conversions.